Error computing phase angle between two time series using Hilbert Transform
I'm trying to compute the phase angle between two time-series of real numbers. To check if my function is working without errors I have created two sine waves with a phase of 17 degrees. However, when I compute the phase angle between those two sine waves I do not get the 17 degrees. Here's my script:
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import hilbert
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def coupling_angle_hilbert(x, y, datatype, center=True, pad=True):
    """
    Compute the phase angle between two time series using the Hilbert transform.

    Parameters:
    - x: numpy array
        Time series data for the first signal.
    - y: numpy array
        Time series data for the second signal.
    - center: bool, optional
        If True, center the amplitude of the data around zero. Default is True.
    - pad: bool, optional
        If True, perform data reflection to address issues arising with data distortion. Default is True.
    - unwrap: bool, optional
        If True, unwrap the phase angle to avoid phase wrapping. Default is True.

    Returns:
    - phase_angle: numpy array
        Phase angle between the two signals.
    """
    
    # Convert input data to radians if specified as degrees
    if datatype.lower().strip() == 'degs':
        x = np.radians(x)
        y = np.radians(y)
    
    # Center the signals if the 'center' option is enabled    
    if center:
       # Adjust x to be centered around zero: subtract minimum, then offset by half the range
        x = x - np.min(x) - ((np.max(x) - np.min(x))/2)
        
        # Adjust y to be centered around zero: subtract minimum, then offset by half the range
        y = y - np.min(y) - ((np.max(y) - np.min(y))/2)

    # Reflect and pad the data if padding is enabled
    if pad:
        # Number of padding samples equal to signal length
        # Ensure that the number of pads is even
        npads = x.shape[0] // 2 * 2  # Ensure npads is even

        # Reflect data at the beginning and end to create padding for 'x' and 'y'
        x_padded = np.concatenate((x[:npads][::-1], x, x[-npads:][::-1]))
        y_padded = np.concatenate((y[:npads][::-1], y, y[-npads:][::-1]))
       
    else:
        # If padding not enabled, use original signals without modification
        x_padded = x
        y_padded = y
                
    # Apply the Hilbert transform to the time series data
    hilbert_x = hilbert(x_padded)
    hilbert_y = hilbert(y_padded)

    # Calculate the phase of each signal by using arctan2 on imaginary and real parts
    phase_angle_x = np.arctan2(hilbert_x.imag, x_padded)
    phase_angle_y = np.arctan2(hilbert_y.imag, y_padded)
    
    # Calculate the phase difference between y and x    
    phase_angle = phase_angle_y - phase_angle_x   

    # Trim the phase_angle to match the shape of x or y
    if pad:
        # Remove initial and ending padding to return only the original signal's phase angle difference
        phase_angle = phase_angle[npads:npads + x.shape[0]]
    
    return phase_angle 

# input data
angles = np.radians(np.arange(0, 360, 1))
phase_offset = np.radians(17)

wav1 = np.sin(angles)
wav2 = np.sin(angles + phase_offset)

# Compute phase_angle usig Hilbert transform    
ca_hilbert =  coupling_angle_hilbert(wav1, 
                                    wav2,
                                    'rads', 
                                    center=True, 
                                    pad=True)

plt.plot(np.degrees(ca_hilbert))
plt.show()

Thank you n advance for any help.

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79153974/error-in-computing-phase-angle-using-angle-angle-plot

Instead of using arctan2(hilbert.imag, x), you can use np.angle(), which returns the argument (angle) of a complex number (always in the range [-π, π]). It's essentially doing arctan2(y, x) for a complex number x + iy.
Also, after phase_angle = phase_y - phase_x, we need to ensure again that it lies in [-π, π], so we do phase_angle = np.angle(np.exp(1j * phase_angle)), following the documentation.
Thus, your function becomes:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import hilbert


def coupling_angle_hilbert(x, y, datatype="rads", center=True, pad=True):
    """
    Compute the phase angle between two time series using the Hilbert transform.

    Parameters:
    - x: numpy array
        Time series data for the first signal.
    - y: numpy array
        Time series data for the second signal.
    - datatype: str, optional
        Specify if input is in 'rads' or 'degs'. Default is 'rads'.
    - center: bool, optional
        If True, center the amplitude of the data around zero. Default is True.
    - pad: bool, optional
        If True, perform data reflection to address issues arising with data distortion. Default is True.

    Returns:
    - phase_angle: numpy array
        Phase angle between the two signals in radians.
    """
    if datatype.lower().strip() == "degs":
        x = np.radians(x)
        y = np.radians(y)

    # Center the signals if the 'center' option is enabled
    if center:
        # Adjust x to be centered around zero: subtract minimum, then offset by half the range
        x = x - np.min(x) - ((np.max(x) - np.min(x)) / 2)

        # Adjust y to be centered around zero: subtract minimum, then offset by half the range
        y = y - np.min(y) - ((np.max(y) - np.min(y)) / 2)

    # Reflect and pad the data if padding is enabled
    if pad:
        # Number of padding samples equal to signal length
        # Ensure that the number of pads is even
        npads = x.shape[0] // 2 * 2  # Ensure npads is even

        # Reflect data at the beginning and end to create padding for 'x' and 'y'
        x_padded = np.concatenate((x[:npads][::-1], x, x[-npads:][::-1]))
        y_padded = np.concatenate((y[:npads][::-1], y, y[-npads:][::-1]))

    else:
        # If padding not enabled, use original signals without modification
        x_padded = x
        y_padded = y

    # Apply the Hilbert transform to the time series data
    hilbert_x = hilbert(x_padded)
    hilbert_y = hilbert(y_padded)

    # Calculate the instantaneous phases
    phase_x = np.angle(hilbert_x)
    phase_y = np.angle(hilbert_y)

    # Calculate the phase difference
    phase_angle = phase_y - phase_x

    # Ensure phase angle is in [-π, π]
    phase_angle = np.angle(np.exp(1j * phase_angle))

    # Trim the phase_angle to match the shape of x or y
    if pad:
        # Remove initial and ending padding to return only the original signal's phase angle difference
        phase_angle = phase_angle[npads : npads + x.shape[0]]

    return phase_angle

With that, I get 17.41 as phase difference.

Thank you for your help. However, after applying the changes you suggested, I was expecting to obtain a phase angle of ~17º for each frame. Instead I'm having higher values in the first (50º) and last frames (>50º), while in the middle frames, the values range between 15º and 20º. The average phase angle across all frames is 20º. My apologies if I misunderstood your explanation but I greatly appreciate your help to understand if I'm missing any step.

That's a feature of the Hilbert transform. You can read up on it more here. But I tried the code as-is with pad=False, which I hadn't done, and I don't get > 50° on the sides, and the mean is 17.02°. I only get that with pad=True. So maybe there is something wrong with the way you're padding. Perhaps, you might want to use np.pad() like: x_padded = np.pad(x, npads, mode=pad_mode); instead of padding it yourself.

Thank you very much for the clarification and all your help. However when using np.pad in both waves (wav1 and wav2) only wav1 padding works as expected. Additionally, I have used reflect_type='odd' and 'even' but it didn't correct the problem. Thus, I will not use padding.
